# Migrating from Oracle to Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration

I need to create a new db in **SQL Server**, and move some data from an **Oracle** db to this SQLServer db;

I read that this function can be implemented by using **SSIS** or the **SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle**;

I wonder if someone can point me to a tutorial or a document where I can see how this task is performed step by step

The data moved from the **Oracle** db is updated on a day basis, so the data moved has to be updated regularly.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-oracle.aspx)?

[Step by step document on how to use it](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/c/8/ec8d5025-7ef7-4dcc-a9f3-9c297cf5350e/SSMAOracle.docx).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

http://aspalliance.com/947_building_a_sql_server_2005_integration_services_package_using_visual_studio_2005

and this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx